# how to hide junit + maven messages

Tags: maven, selenium, junit, maven-surefire-plugin, selenide

I am using Selenide under Maven.
I tried to hide maven log messages by calling `mvn -q`.
And for Selenide logs I tried to use the following solution:

- Add JVM option:

> -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Temp\logging.properties

- Create file logging.properties contining something like this:

> handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler .level=INFO
>   com.codeborne.selenide.level=SEVERE

But still I have the following appeared when calling `mvn -q test`

- Starting ChromeDriver (v2.9.248315) on port 33356
- junit messages:

  ```
  T E S T S

   --------------------------------------------------------
  Running sa.vanilla.test.logintest.Vanilla_Login_successfully
  Starting ChromeDriver (v2.9.248315) on port 13890
  Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 30.465 sec

  Results :
  ```

**Question**: How to Hide all the previous log messages? I need only my print out messages to be appeared.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed even running the test phase with the quite option (`-q`) still shows the following output:

```
-------------------------------------------------------   
 T E S T S   
-------------------------------------------------------  
Running be.axa.training.hello.HelloModelTest   
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.078 sec  
Running be.axa.training.hello.HelloAppTestCase   
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 sec  

Results :  

Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Using Maven Surefire Plugin version **2.19.1** (the latest at the moment) and using the [`printSummary`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#printSummary) option to false, hence running:

```
mvn test -q -Dsurefire.printSummary=false
```

Still gives the following output:

```
-------------------------------------------------------   
 T E S T S   
-------------------------------------------------------   
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

However (and surprisingly) using Maven Surefire Plugin version **2.5** with the option above, doesn't print anything, you get empty output! So the way the `printSummary` option is used has changed over versions.

You can get to use this version adding it explicitly to your pom, like as following:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

A quick test to check the difference between the two versions would be to explicitly invoke the two versions as following:

```
mvn -q org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.5:test -Dsurefire.printSummary=false
```

and

```
mvn -q org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test -Dsurefire.printSummary=false
```

And check the different results (the first would only show output of test cases, the second would also show the Surefire tests summary).

So, if you are not using any new feature of the Maven Surefire Plugin from version **2.5** on, the solution above may suit your needs.

However, using an old version just for a printing functionality is certainly not recommended.

Comment: @Hanaa did this answer help? you didn't accept it nor share further details.